# Are the tags [editing] and [text-editing] useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag [editing](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing):

- [How to add a prefix to every line?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/11/how-to-add-a-prefix-to-every-line)
- [How to delete the first few n chars of every line?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-to-delete-the-first-few-n-chars-of-every-line)
- [Is there a way to use query-replace from grep/ack/ag output modes?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/212/is-there-a-way-to-use-query-replace-from-grep-ack-ag-output-modes)

and [text-editing](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-editing):

- [How to add a prefix to every line?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/11/how-to-add-a-prefix-to-every-line)

Inasmuch they are useful, we should keep one, as they seem to mean the same thing.

While I can see what the tag is supposed to mean — questions about changing text in a buffer — having a tag called “(text-)editing” on a site about a (text) editor is weird. I'm not convinced that the tag is sustainable: tags with overly general face meanings are prone to misuse. Do we need a tag about this concept? Can we find a better name?

Answer (score 5):

> having a tag called “(text-)editing” on a site about a (text) editor is weird.

I thought so too. Then I paid a visit to the front page and took a stroll about our questions. I could find at most a couple of questions there which fit this tag. All the others are about displaying, interaction, customization, etc. *{Insert joke that emacs's not a text editor here.}*

Although very broad tags do tend to be misused, it might just be that this tag isn't too broad after all.

**Regarding which version to use**.
This is a very minor consideration, but "text-editing" could be mistaken to mean "prose-editing" (as in not code).